# Mongodb query exact match not an array

Tags: mongodb

I'm querying for a document with `{"foo": "a"}`, not `{"foo":["a", "b"]}`.

How do I make the exact query in mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surprisingly difficult due to issue [SERVER-1475](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1475) which causes the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/) of the `foo` field in both cases to be reported as a string.

One workaround is to test for the existence of an array element to detect the array case (and exclude it from the results):

```js
db.test.find({$and: [{'foo.0': {$exists: false}}, {foo: 'a'}]})
```